# How to deal with the following symbol: ¶

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm kinda new to Python. I need to read some text from one file (A), compare it with the text from another file (B), change a part of the earlier mentioned file and write it to the third one (C). Problem is A and B files files have unusual notation that involves this symbol "¶".

So, I managed to bypass it (ignore it) by reading (or writing) in the following way:

```
input = codecs.open('bla.txt', 'r', 'ascii', 'ignore');
```

But it's not good. I NEED to read it in precise way and compare it and write successfully.

So, content of my B file is: `"Sugar=[Sugar@Butter¶Cherry]"`
but when I read it, my variable has the value `Sugar=[Sugar@ButterÂ¶Cherry]`
You can see, there is additional "Â"

Then my A file contains a lot of text which needs to be copied to the C file, except the certain part that follows after the above mentioned text in in B. That part needs to be changed and then written, BUT they are not the same, my program never enters the IF condition in which I am comparing the `"Sugar=[Sugar@Butter¶Cherry]"` form A and `"Sugar=[Sugar@Butter¶Cherry]"` from B.

Is there a way I can read the text so that this symbol "¶" appears as it is?

Comment: My standard advice applies: read [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](http://joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html) by Joel Spolsky, The [Python Unicode HOWTO](http://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html), and [Pragmatic Unicode](http://nedbatchelder.com/text/unipain.html) by Ned Batchelder before you continue. Then open the file as UTF-8 and decode to Unicode values.

Comment: My sys.stdin.encoding is cp1252

Comment: Hoa, my problem was encoding difference between file A and file B. One was UTF-8 and another one was ascii, and that was the reason in undesired reading. Thanks for those recommendations, they are quite useful for someone like I am. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

Use the correct encoding.

```
input = codecs.open('bla.txt', 'r', 'UTF-8', 'ignore')
```

Comment: Now that we have `io` in Python 2, use [`io.open()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/io.html#io.open) instead. The `codecs` library has some rather nasty bugs when it comes to buffering, and it doesn't handle encoding errors very elegantly either.

Comment: I'd drop the `ignore`; it's better to get an error and know you've picked the wrong encoding when you want to deal with text correctly than to ignore the problems.